# How to set different select items in Vaadin Grid Pro's editComponent based on row item

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin14, vaadin-grid

I have Grid Pro displaying Products. A single column is configured as an EditColumn of type 'select' (dropdown/combobox). I'm trying to set the items for this component based on the Product of that row. Is this possible using the 'select' editColumn?

I tried to achieve what I want using the grid's 'addCellEditStartedListener' event, but I can't seems to access the editComponent from CellEditStartedEvent..

thx!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the this is missing feature in `CellEditStartedEvent`. As an alternative you can use custom editor in your edit column, as then you have reference to the field you are using, see example

```
    // Use custom editor
    EmailField emailField = new EmailField();
    emailField.setWidth("100%");
    emailField.addThemeName("grid-pro-editor");
    grid.addEditColumn(Person::getEmail)
            .custom(emailField, (item, newValue) -> {
                item.setEmail(newValue);
            }).setHeader("E-mail ");
    // Use edit started listener to set the field conditionally enabled
    grid.addCellEditStartedListener(event -> {
        if (!event.getItem().isSubscriber()) {
            emailField.setReadOnly(true);
        } else {
            emailField.setReadOnly(false);
        }
    });
```

Full code here: https://cookbook.vaadin.com/grid-pro-conditional-edit